# В MainMenuScreen установить фоновое изображение

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Подскажите ,как на задний фон меню установить фоновое изображение.
Использую скин для кнопки.

```
  texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.png"));
```

Если делать через `batch.draw(texture, 10, 10);` ,то фоновое изображение появляется,Но закрывает кнопку

```
   public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen {
    private Texture texture;
    final Drop game;
    Skin skin;
    Stage stage;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    TextButton newGameButton;


    private void createBasicSkin() {
        //Create a font
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.png"));

// Skin читает стили из файла из настройками и сохраняет их внутри себя.
        BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();
        skin = new Skin();
        skin.add("default", font);
//Растровое изображение представляет собой изображение в памяти.
        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap((int)Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/4,(int)Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/10, Pixmap.Format.RGB888);
        pixmap.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        pixmap.fill();
        skin.add("background",new Texture(pixmap));

        //Create a button style
        TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle.up = skin.newDrawable("background", Color.GRAY);
        textButtonStyle.down = skin.newDrawable("background", Color.DARK_GRAY);
        textButtonStyle.checked = skin.newDrawable("background", Color.DARK_GRAY);
        textButtonStyle.over = skin.newDrawable("background", Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        textButtonStyle.font = skin.getFont("default");
        skin.add("default", textButtonStyle);

    }
        public MainMenuScreen(final Drop gam) {
        game = gam;

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();

        camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
           stage = new Stage();
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);// Make the stage consume events

            createBasicSkin();
        newGameButton = new TextButton("New game", skin); // Use the initialized skin
            newGameButton.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/8 , Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
            stage.addActor(newGameButton);

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        if (newGameButton.isChecked()) {
            game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
            dispose();
        }

        stage.act();
        stage.draw();

    }




    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте вызывать batch.draw перед рисованием кнопки. Сначала рисуйте фон, а потом, поверх все остальное